# UI Tabs set Title

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to set the title in tabs, but title is displayed behind the background.
If in this class #tabss .ui-tabs-nav i set background: transparent; then show my title otherwise displayed behind the background.

code css:

```
#tabss {
padding: 0px;
background: none;
border-width: 0px;
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
zoom:1;
}

#tabss .ui-tabs-nav {
background: url("img/top-bg-column.gif") repeat;
border:0px;
//background: transparent;
text-align: right;
zoom:2;
height:30px;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
#tabss .ui-tabs-nav li { display: inline-block; float: none; border-color:#dfdfdf; position: relative; top: 1px; margin: 1px 0 0 0;  white-space: nowrap; }
#tabss .ui-tabs-nav li a { color:#222; background: url("img/top-bg-column-hover.gif"); font-weight:normal; padding:2px 10px 4px 10px; }
#tabss .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover { color:#666; background:#f7f7f7; }
#tabss .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { background:#f7f7f7; color:#666;  }
#tabss .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { top:3px; }
#tabss .ui-tab-title { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; font-size:18px; color:red; zoom:3; }
#tabss .ui-tabs-panel {
background-color:#f7f7f7;
border-color:#dfdfdf;
border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
padding: 10px;
 }
```

code html:

```
<div id="tabss" class="tabs">
  <p class="ui-tab-title">My Title</p>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
   // data
  </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
   // data
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for this? Issue s not clear now.

Comment: pls check this link http://s7.postimage.org/xat8olbuj/image.png , in class .ui-tab-title i change top:-10px; to see where is my text title.

Comment: if you want "My Title" div to bring front, please just assign high z-index value and check..

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to the following. Deleted `<p class="ui-tab-title">My Title</p>`

```
<div id="tabss" class="tabs">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
   // data
  </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
   // data
  </div>
 </div>
```

Then add the following code after creating the UI tabs.

```
$('#tabss').prepend('<p class="ui-tab-title">My Title</p>');
```

** If this is not you wanted, then please update more details

Comment: Title still show me behind the background like this link http://s7.postimage.org/xat8olbuj/image.png

Comment: If i change this class #tabss .ui-tabs-nav { background: none; } then show my title, what is wrong with background ?

Comment: Can you show a live sample? I am not able to guess your issue. My solution is working with jQuery tab plugin (with default formatting)

Comment: I'm working on localhost, can you try implement with my css code

Comment: Then create a sample [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)... That will help us...

Comment: Strange in jsfiddle title is not behind background jsfiddle.net/adBsA/

Comment: Yea. It is happening because of some other style you mentioned in your project

Comment: thanks for helping i found solution, и used an older version because the title is on display behind background